Web Server in C++
Planning on writing a set of blog articles on how to write a web server.
So each phase will have a new version of the server with extra features. But starting very basic and working up to a reasonable (not apache good) server written in C++ that people can take and play with.
Before I go and show the code in an article I hope I can get some feedback here to make sure I don't do anything too stupid.
Version 1: Hello World
A very simple server. Accepts requests and returns a page.
Note: All streams are blocking. So we can only process one page at a time.
  #include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
  #include <ThorsSocket/Socket.h>
  #include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
  #include <charconv>
  #include <iostream>


  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      std::cout << PACKAGE_STRING << " Server\n";

      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLctx;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Socket;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::ServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Blocking;

      int port = 8080;
      if (argc > 1) {
          port = std::stoi(argv[1]);
      }

  #define EXAMPLE_CERTIFICATE_INFO    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/"

  #ifdef CERTIFICATE_INFO
      // If you have site certificate set CERTIFICATE_INFO to the path
      // This will then create an HTTPS server.
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo;
      CertificateInfo certificate{CERTIFICATE_INFO "fullchain.pem",
                                  CERTIFICATE_INFO "privkey.pem"
                                 };
      SSLctx          ctx{SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
      Server          server{SServerInfo{port, ctx}};
  #else
      // Without a site certificate you should only use an HTTP port.
      // But most modern browsers are going to complain.
      // See: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/
      //      On how to get a free signed site certificate.
      Server          server{ServerInfo{port}};
  #endif

      while (true)
      {
          Socket          accept = server.accept(Blocking::No);
          SocketStream    stream(std::move(accept));

          std::string line;
          std::size_t bodySize = 0;
          for (bool closeSocket = false; !closeSocket;)
          {
              closeSocket = true;
              while (std::getline(stream, line))
              {
                  std::cout << "Request: " << line << "\n";
                  if (line == "\r") {
                      break;
                  }
                  if (line.compare("Content-Length: ") == 0) {
                      std::from_chars(&line[0] + 16, &line[0] + line.size(), bodySize);
                  }
                  if (line == "Connection: keep-alive\r") {
                      closeSocket = false;
                  }
              }
              stream.ignore(bodySize);

              stream << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                     << "Content-Length: 135\r\n"
                     << "\r\n"
                     << R"(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html>
  <head><title>Nissa server 1.1</title></head>
  <body>Hello world</body>
  </html>)";
              stream.flush();
              std::cout << "Done\n";
          }
     }

  }

Note: I am using some basic streaming library that I have written and previously had code reviewed "ThorsSocket". It is available on GitHub but easier to download via brew.
Link with: -lThorsSocket -lThorsLogging

This is meant to be a follow-up to @GSliepen’s review; I thought it would be a good idea to illustrate and expand on their suggestions.
So, as they suggested, splitting the main() into functions would make the code much better, not least because it would break it up into clear and distinct steps.
For example, something like:
auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    auto const options = parse_options(argc, argv);

    auto server = initialize_server(options);

    while (server.is_accepting_connections())
    {
        auto connection = accept_connection(server);
        auto stream = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream{std::move(connection)};

        while (stream)
        {
            auto request = parse_request(stream);
            handle_request(request, stream):
        }
    }
}

In my opinion, the most important important features tutorial code should have are being:

simple
clear; and
easy to extend.

Being easy to extend is an often unappreciated feature of tutorial code, but the way I see it, the point of a tutorial is to give you a starting point to build on. By breaking it up into each, distinct, logical, and “interesting” step, it’s much easier to figure out where one can insert new stuff.
For example, a beginner could be challenged to queue up requests, so that if a bunch of similar requests are made within a certain time span, a single computation can be done and the results served to multiple clients, or a computation can be cached, so that the results can be re-used by multiple requests by the same client. With the structure above, it is very easy to see multiple ways to accomplish this: you could remove handle_request() and replace it with pushing to a queue that is pumped in the outer while (perhaps by changing the condition to while (accepting-connections or queue-not-empty)), or you could do the queuing in handle_request(), or whatever.
Or they could be challenged to implement logging of requests: Easy to do, just insert logging logic between parse_request() and handle_request().
Basically, you want to consider things that the students can be challenged or inspired on their own to do to extend the tutorial, and structure the code to make such “improvements” easy to do. The most obvious way to do that is to make each atomically “interesting” step its own function.
Now, I do agree that the macros and conditional compilation are bad form, and not a great idea as demonstration code for beginners, but I disagree that adding TLS support is unwise. The way I see it, there are two realistic goals for someone who wants to implement their own server in C++:

They want to make a web application of some kind.
Realistically, such a web app will almost certainly be behind a reverse proxy that will do all the heavy lifting of handling the TLS and dealing with naughty clients and malformed requests. For such cases, TLS support will be superfluous, because the only thing connecting to the app will be the reverse proxy (which, presumably, will be an internal connection).

They want to make a tiny server, perhaps for an IoT device or something similar.
In this case, they will probably want TLS support, because they won’t be using a reverse proxy, because they probably can’t afford the overhead of something like Nginx on their microcontroller.


I think any tutorial demonstrating making an HTTP server or client in 2024 would be their readers a disservice if it doesn’t include TLS support.
But let’s take a step back for a moment, and focus on configuration. Your current code kinda mixes paradigms: on the one hand you hard-code configuration with preprocessor constants, and on the other you parse the command line.
I would suggest that for a tutorial on making a web server, all configuration code is irrelevant. That’s all stuff the reader can figure out on their own if they want to extend the tutorial code into something useful for them.
It also sidesteps problems like the question of whether std::stoi() is a good idea. That discussion is a complete red herring for an HTTP server.
So I would suggest just hard-coding all configuration. Readers can adjust the constants for their own situation if they want, or implement actual configure-ability via the command line or configuration files.
Like so:
struct program_options
{
    std::string server_name;
    int         port;

    bool    use_tls;

    std::filesystem::path   full_certificate_chain;
    std::filesystem::path   private_key;

    // Any other configuration options, like choosing interfaces, IPv4/6, etc.
};

auto parse_options([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char* argv[])
{
    auto options = program_options{};

    options.server_name = "www.example.com";
    options.port        = 8080;

    // TLS is off by default; if you enable it, make sure you have a valid
    // certificate for the domain you are serving.
    options.use_tls = false;
    if (options.use_tls)
    {
        // These paths assume you are using LetsEncrypt:
        auto certificates_directory = std::filesystem::path{"/etc/letsencrypt/live"} / options.server_name;

        options.full_certificate_chain  = certificates_directory / "fullchain.pem";
        options.private_key             = certificates_directory / "privkey.pem";
    }

    return options;
}

auto initialize_server(program_options const& opts)
{
    if (opts.use_tls)
    {
        auto certificate = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo{
            opts.full_certificate_chain,
            opts.private_key
        };

        auto tls_context = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLctx{
            ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType::Server,
            std::move(certificate)
        };

        return ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server{
            ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SServerInfo{
                opts.port,
                std::move(tls_context)
            }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server{
            ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::ServerInfo{opts.port}
        };
    }
}

// Same main() as above:
auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    // ...
}

Given that, any C++ newbie that is capable of understanding the rest of the server code can very easily extend the list of options and/or implement loading configuration from the command line or configuration files. They can also validate a configuration, either while parsing or during initialization.
This all amounts to more code, but, again, that cost is massively subsidized by the fact that it makes things much easier to modify or extend.
To that end I’d add to the comment that hard-coding the response content length is a bad idea. If you think about it, the very first thing someone is going to want to do after reading the tutorial is to change the output that is delivered from the server.
What you really need is a “send response” function that you can pass headers and content to. Something like:
auto send_response(
    ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream& stream,
    std::map<std::string, std::string> const& headers,
    std::string const& body
)
{
    stream << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";

    for (auto const& [header, value] : headers)
        stream << header << ": " << value << "\r\n";

    // Some other important headers to send for security reasons:
    stream << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n";
    stream << "X-Frame-Options: DENY\r\n";
    stream << "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n";

    stream << "Content-Length: " << body.size() << "\r\n";

    stream << "\r\n";

    stream << body;
}

Which could be used like:
struct request
{
    std::string path;
    bool keep_alive;
    // ... etc.
};

auto handle_request(
    [[maybe_unused]] request const& req,
    ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream& stream
)
{
    // Just return default data:
    auto content = R"(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Nissa server 1.1</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>)";

    auto headers = std::map<std::string, std::string>{
        {"Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"},
        {"Content-Language", "en"},
    };

    send_response(stream, headers, content);
}

Of course, a better design would be to have a dedicated class for headers that you can add headers to, then stream the whole thing out at once, but maybe that’s not necessary for a tutorial.
But with just the above, a reader can trivially change the content served (perhaps based on the request path), add/remove headers, use chunked encoding, and other interesting stuff, like maybe check the request header for accept-language, and serve the document in English, Français, or Español, or even parsing GET requests with query parameters, or POST requests with form data.
A few final comments…:
As was mentioned, keeping the connection open is the default, but also, connection control headers like Connection and Keep-Alive are illegal as of HTTP/2, so, maybe all the stuff involving that is just not worth including. You could maybe have a comment that if the reader is interested, they can check for connection: close and close the connection.
Regarding namespaces, I’m not a fan of:
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLctx;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Socket;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::ServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Blocking;

In a tutorial, I would recommend leaving the namespaces (mostly) intact, because a reader really needs to know where, for example, SSLctx comes from. If they’re trying to understand the code, and still in the early stages of the struggling with the concepts, when they see:
      SSLctx          ctx{SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
      Server          server{SServerInfo{port, ctx}};

… they are now going to have to figure out where SSLctx, SSLMethodType, Server, and SServerInfo come from. That means the extra step of searching for using directives or going through documentation. Even later in the process, once they’ve got the concepts and want to now extend the tutorial code, they will probably need to know where these things come from. Stripping the namespaces doesn’t help them.
Granted, the namespaces here do get a little long, so spelling them out in full may even be distracting. But for that there are namespace aliases:
namespace ThorsSocket = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket;

ThorsSocket::SSLctx ctx{ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
ThorsSocket::Server server{ThorsSocket::SServerInfo{port, ctx}};

You could even use something shorter than ThorsSocket as the alias (TSock, maybe?), for even less noise. So long as all the types are qualified, it’s still clear that they’re part of a particular namespace, and which one.
To summarize, I think tutorial code should have a few characteristics:

Everything not immediately relevant to the “thing” being taught should pared down as much as possible.
In particular, configuration stuff should just be flat out hard-coded. If the reader wants to implement run-time configure-ability via the command line or configuration files, let that be their problem.

Nothing that is relevant should be removed or hidden.
In particular, the namespaces of types are very relevant. You can certainly simplify them with aliases. But I don’t think removing them is a good idea.
(Opinion here: I think giving beginners the idea that completely stripping namespaces is “normal” is doing them a disservice. Better to get them used to seeing the std::s and ThorsAnvil::s from the start, so they learn from the beginning that namespace-qualified types and such is what “normal” C++ code “looks like”. Demonstrating how a namespace alias can shorten long namespaces is a very good thing to illustrate.)

Every logical and “interesting” step should be clearly defined and isolated, as distinct functions if possible.
This not only makes it easier to see and understand each logical step, it makes it much easier to extend the tutorial code by adding new stuff in or between steps.

One of my teaching mantras is that C++ is a strongly-typed language, and if you get the types right, everything else Just Works™. However, there is a tension in tutorial code.
In “real” code, you would definitely want to make proper, dedicated types for things like (for example) HTTP headers—both for setting (for example, to make sure header names are legal, and they are not duplicated (except for ones that can be)) and for parsing (for example, to handle case-insensitivity when checking for certain headers).
But for tutorial code, the effort of making such proper types could be distracting from the main point. And yet, if teaching best practices, you should be doing that anyway.
What I would suggest is making simple, “rough” types that mostly do the job. For example, for a header: tuple<string, string> or, better, struct header { string name; string value; }; or, even better, class header { public: name() -> string; value() -> string; private: string _name; string _value; }; to start.
If the types are simple enough, then far from being distracting, they could actually make the important parts of the code easier to understand. And, of course, you will at least be roughly exemplifying good C++ code. The reader could then be challenged to make those rough, simple types better, on their own.
I get that you plan to “class-ify” everything later, in a further tutorial, but I don’t think that’s a good way to teach C++. I’m not a fan of “do it wrong/ugly then fix it” style of teaching. I prefer “do it simple then make more capable/robust”. So right from the start you should show types for the server, requests, headers, and so on. Very simple types, with little/no error checking, but types with basically the same interface as the final design, so they can be fleshed out with little impact on the rest of the code. I think that would be demonstrating good C++ programming at the same time as the primary tutorial concepts, which is a good thing.


Hope that helps!

queue up requests: Nice addition.

hard-coding the response content length is a bad idea: Agreed. But the plan is a second tutorial about handling HTTP processing response as a second tutorial. But I will make that note explicit.

You could even use something shorter than ThorsSocket as the alias: In my personal code I like namespace aliases of 3-5 letters (just like std:: is only 3 letters. So namespace TSock = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket; falls into what I would normally do.

if you get the types right, everything else Just Works™ Preach.

but types with basically the same interface as the final design: Yes came to the same conclusion while writing the changes from article to article.

My compiler does not support std::jthread even with the -std=c++20 flag. Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3)

Yikes, without jthread everything gets a lot trickier. Even the seemingly simple creation of the thread pool is fraught. When you do workers = vector<thread>{}; for (n...) workers.emplace(thread{func});, if any of those threads fail to be created, you have to deal with the ones that were already made—that is, stop their thread funcs, and join them. Possible, sure, but messy, where jthread just does everything right automatically.

Avoid macros
Try to avoid macros, it makes the code harder to read. That's especially important for example code. You should be able to rewrite the code without using them.
Consider whether it makes sense to add SSL support to the example: do people already have a domain and working certificates that are accepted by the browser? If not, do you expect them to go spend the rest of the day getting that set up to then be able to run the example?
Split your code into multiple functions
Your main() is quite busy. Split it into multiple functions, each doing a single thing, like setting up the listening socket, accepting connections and serving a single request.
Header parsing
You are using a very simplistic way of parsing the request header. It's bound to simplify things too much, and therefore react incorrectly to some headers. For example, the Connection header can be a comma-separated list, which does not need to contain the word keep-alive, and still mean that the connection should be kept open. Also, keeping the connection open is the default for HTTP/1.1 requests.
While it keeps the example short, it teaches something wrong.
Content-Length generation
It's quite easy to miss that if you change the body of the response, you also need to update the value for Content-Length in the header. I would rewrite it so it calculates the content length automatically.
Who is this for?
You are writing this code for a very small group of people. Even if you take the group of people that want to write a web server themselves, how many of them want to use an existing library to take care of network sockets, but not use a library to take care of HTTP request parsing and response generation? I'd rather see a blog of how to use ThorsAnvil::ThorsWebServer.

A tutorial that encourages folks to use Let's Encrypt for certs is not putting too big of a speedbump into the process.

Let’s Encrypt requires a public domain. That is a hell of a speedbump if all you’re teaching is how to code an HTTP(S) server. It would make more sense to teach how to generate a snake oil certificate.

Also, keeping the connection open is the default for HTTP/1.1 requests. Good to know. But why does this header exist then?

@indi What do you mean how to generate a snake oil certificate?

The header exists for other things than just keeping the connection open, but specifically keep-alive is for backwards compatibility with HTTP/1.0 (see RFC2068).

“Snake oil” cert is slang for a self-signed certificate. Self-signed certs are not trusted by default, because you can literally claim to be anybody (you could make a cert claiming you’re codereview.stackexchange.com). To be trusted, a cert has to be signed by a trusted certificate authority. There is a way you can become a CA, get the browser to trust you, and then sign your own certs. It only works locally, but allows you to test HTTPS privately with any domain you please (https://thor.local, or https://nissa.thor, or whatever), without needing a public domain.
